# With Twilio, can you get a notification when a queue add/removes a member?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to do some server side queue management with a an application I am writing, using Twilio (C# MVC project).  Is there any way to receive a notification of some sort when a caller is added to or removed from a queue without constantly having to check the queue myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest looking into using the *waitUrl* and *action* parameters on the `[<Enqueue>][1]` verb.

The url provided in the waitUrl param is requested when the user enters the queue.  The url in the action parameter is requested when the caller leaves the queue.

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/09/building-a-queue-metrics-dashboard.html) a while ago that shows how to create a dashboard un ASP.NET MVC that displays current queue size and average time in queue using those two parameters.  It should be pretty straight forward to adapt the post to whatever language and framework your working with.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. Somehow, I had completely overlooked the "action" attribute for dequeueing.